# Change the jqm page id when requesting page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to build something like bbui for my website.
With bbui I can do bb.Pushscreen('file.html','fileid');

Than it put's it in the body.
I build the same but I want to change the page ID also depending on the requested page.

```
<a href="#" onClick="jqmPushscreen('test.html','test');">tab</a>


var id = '';
function jqmPushscreen(page,id) {
var page = page;
var id = id;
$('page').attr('id',id);
$.ajax({
    url: page,
    success: function (data) { 
    $('#content').html(data); 
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});

}
```

It loads the file in the #content div:

```
<div data-role="content" id="content">
```

But this part:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="" class="page">
```

Needs to change also, I tried more examples.
The other thing that doesn't work is this.

// Fires "after" styling is applied and "after" the screen is inserted in the DOM

```
$( window ).load(function() { 
if(id == "test") { console.log("loaded test 2"); }

});
```

Because at this point it cannot find the ID.
I also tried:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').attr('id', id);
```

But none of the values gives me something.

I tried putting:

```
var id = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");
```

and

```
id = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");
```

in my

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

and

```
$( window ).load(function() {
```

This is the div I try to change:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="" class="page">
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: `$('page').attr('id',id);` you mean `$(page).attr('id',id);` as `page` is a var? It shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: page is a var but also the class of the div

Comment: If a class `$(".page")`. Don't use `.ready()` in JQM, use JQM events.

Comment: Also, append pages to `$.mobile.pageContainer`.